# Negative lookup string in PHP ( Regular expression)

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this

```
<div tagname="chapter_title" class="CHAP_TTL" aidpstyle="CHAP_TTL">testt</div>
<div tagname="section" id="sec01">
<div tagname="title" class="H1" aidpstyle="H1" id="sec01">
     INTRODUCTION<!--title-->
</div>
<div tagname="para" class="CHAP_BM_FIRST" aidpstyle="CHAP_BM_FIRST">test3
<div tagname="emph" class="ITALIC" aidcstyle="ITALIC">buildings</div>
```

I'm trying to find the DIV that doesnot contain word (emph,section) in tagname attribute

I used the below pattern but its not showing the right output

```
 preg_match_all('/<div tagname="(?!emph)(?!section)(?!footnote)
      (?!note).*"/i',$new_updated_html,$divstarttag);
```

Any takers ??

Comment: Obligatory [don't use regex to parse html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?page=1&tab=votes#1732454) link.

Comment: Agreed. PHP has a perfectly good [DOM parser class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Answer (score 3):

I checked your code and its works fine except that you need to replace all the new lines and spaces using following two lines-

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $subject);

$data = preg_replace('/\r\n/', "", $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [PHP Simple DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) (or any other PHP HTML parsing framework). Using regular expressions for HTML is something which you should avoid. The DOM Parser should allow you to iterate over the `div` sections in your document and access the relevant information.